# How to fill the space occupied by hidden fields

Tags: html, css

I have a form with 3 fieldset's and all are hidden.
Depending on user's choice the particular fieldset is set visible.
Problem is- how to fill the spaces occupied by the hidden fieldset ? Because each time a fieldset is set visible the space occupied by first fieldset is also visible.
I tried using -
style="visibility: hidden; overflow : auto".

Thanks for upcoming suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of hiding them, set their **display** property to `none` like this:

```
display: none;
```

This will prevent them from taking up space when they are not visible. To make them visible, set the display property to `block` like this:

```
display: block;
```